# voice recognition in android for send email

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I am developing application which will open android application using voice command.
Android has provide some intent to open browser,to search word.

I want to send mail using voice command as done by voice search application of Google.
I didn't get any intent to invoke email application.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible specifically in such a way that you have a Listener, you listen to the message and decode what you need and find out if you need to do something. You'd pass in an Intent based on what you recieve in the voice message.

Answer (score 0):

To add to *JoxTraex*, you can use the ACTION_SEND intent with appropriate fields set to launch the mail application.